# Php mysql routine for calculating in one table and place results in another table

Tags: php, mysql

I need a php routine for my mysql database. I have made an example to illustrate the problem:

Lets say I have a table that registrates customers and how much money they spend. A customer can have more registrations:

```
Table1: 
Name - Amount
Jane - 3
Mark - 4
Sara - 5
Jane - 5
Jane - 6
Sara - 2
```

I want a routine that goes trough Table1, and finds how much each person has spend. I want the result in Table2, like this:

```
Table2:
Jane - 14
Mark - 4
Sara - 7
```

Do you have a solution to this?

Comment: What's your PRIMARY KEY?

Answer (score 1):

```
insert into table2 select name, sum(amount) from table1 group by name;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT Name, SUM(Amount) FROM Table1 GROUP BY Name
```